# GAE HttpServletRequest - How can I use getUserPrincipal with my own login mechanism?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

**Precedent**

In GAE, when we use the built-in [Users Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers) to log in a user, GAE automagically sets the `HttpServletRequest` so that:

- `getUserPrincipal()` returns the user name or null if no user is logged in
- `isUserInRole()` verifies if the user meets a role

**My question**

I am now implementing an independent login mechanism for which I need to track whether the user is logged-in through the duration of the session.

I see that many of people use `HttpServletRequest`'s `getSession.setAttribute` with custom parameters as the mean to store login data for the session.

However, I wonder if there is a way of leveraging the built-in functions `getUserPrincipal` and `isUserInRole`the same way that GAE uses them. Or is this functionality reserved by GAE for their internal Users Service and not accessible to us users?

Comment: Im pretty sure you cant leverage that unless you use the built-in login (like openid). In any case, isUserInRole etc will only work for appengine project users (google accounts), the only role that exists is admin and those are hardcoded to the appengine project members configuration.